# Save file in spring and read by web

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to record a temporary file in Spring and read it on the web. The problem is that Spring saves it in a folder that the browser can not access.

Spring ----> MyProject ----> MyFolder

i need:

Spring ---> MyProject ----> scr/main/resources/temp

how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

How do you write the file? Can you please post your source code?
I assume that you run the app as WAR or JAR. So you cannot write to this and the src is not in the JAR/WAR. You must write it outside your deployment and the read from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring with MVC + MAVEN.

My engraving code is as follows:

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("MyFolder/file.txt"));

he is recording it in:

MyProyect ---> MyFolder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmIl7.png)

But in my browser I can not access there

localhost:8080/myfolder/file.txt